# Link values between MS excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in MS Excel, both on separate sheets, `Table A` on `Sheet 1` and `Table B` on `Sheet 2`, `Table A` column `longname` is fed from an external database, however I am trying to populate the same `Table A` column `shortname` with the matching `shortname` value shown in `table b`, also if a new `longname` is fed from the external database into `table A` example `Riders` with corresponding shortname `RDR` is added, I would manually add this along with the `shortname` to `Table B`. My question is how do I get the `shortname` column in `table A` to automatically produce the corresponding character, even when the new Data is added in `Table B`, I have an expected result to show exactly what i am trying to achieve.

```
Table A

 shortname  longname
                 Hynes
                 Hynes
                 Our Society
                 Hynes
                 Hynes
                 Travellers
                 Our Society
                 The Dwellers
                 Campers
                 Travellers
                 Our Society
                 Hynes
                 Hynes
```

Table B

```
shortname   Longname
DH          Hynes
TRS         Travellers
CMPRS           Campers
CC          Cash Cow
TDW         The Dwellers
OSR         Our Society
```

expected result

```
Shortname   Longname
DH          Hynes
DH          Hynes
OSR         Our Society
DH          Hynes
DH          Hynes
TRS         Travellers
RDR         Riders
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap the column names on Table B and do a vlookup for the Short Name on Table A.